# Python Forking in multiprocessing Process vs Pool

Tags: python, memory, process, multiprocessing, fork

I came across this question:

I wanted to make use of forking and inheritance of memory-objects with python for efficient memory usage in a multiprocessing setting.

*(This code example is not to examplify the use of Pool in multiprocessing, it should outline what Python does when starting a new process in a Pool or with calling Process!)*

**Variant 1**

```
import pickle, time, signal
import multiprocessing as mp


class Compute:

    def __init__(self):
        self.manager = mp.Manager()
        self.manager_dict = self.manager.dict()
        self.big_data = pickle.load(open("big_data_object.pkl", "rb"))

    def compute(self, task_id):
        ## do something wigh big data here use self.big_data
        ## for i in self.big_data:
        time.sleep(2)
        self.manager_dict[task_id] = "Result"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    comp = Compute()
    task_id = 1

    st = time.time()
    p = mp.Process(target=comp.compute, args=(task_id,))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    result = comp.manager_dict[task_id]
    print(result)
    print("duration: ", time.time() - st)
```

**Variant 2**

```
class Compute:

    def __init__(self):
        self.big_data = pickle.load(open("big_data_object.pkl", "rb"))

    def compute(self, task_id):
        ## do something wigh big data here use self.big_data
        ## for i in self.big_data:
        time.sleep(2)
        return "Result"


if __name__ == '__main__':

    comp = Compute()
    task_id = 1
    compute_input = [task_id]
    st = time.time()

    with mp.Pool() as p:
        for result in p.imap_unordered(comp.compute, compute_input):
            print(result)
    print("duration: ", time.time()-st)
```

Then I ran into the following two different methodos to perform this. Unfortunately, the **Variant 2** runs **twice** as long, as the **Variant 1**.

I could find in debugging that the **Pool** methodolgy actually does serialize all the objects and deserilizes it again in the new child proccess, which takes of course more time.

The Process variant in 1, does not do this and acutally use inheritance of memory objects.

Could someone with experience in python multiprocessing explain why this is happening here, it does not seem like wanted behaviour for **forking** in multiprocessing.

*(the program needs to be run on Unix/Linux OS for forking)*

Comment: First, your first example didn't run.  I had to move `manager = mp.Manager()` to `__main__`, and then pass the manager as an argument to `__init__` (and not store it) to get the code to run.  That fixed, both versions of your code run in nearly identical times on my computer.

Comment: @FrankYellin concerning the manager code, this is not correct. The code runs with the maanger initiliazed directly in init, not sure what happens on your end.

Comment: Also make sure that the big_data file is in memory at least up to 300 - 500mb big, to see differences.

Comment: If your platform uses methods *spawn* to create new child processes, then **Variant 1** *will* generate `TypeError: cannot pickle 'weakref' object`.

Comment: Yes @Booboo that's why I have written run on Linux OS, to use forking

Comment: On a separate line of thought, relying on copy-on-write is fickle in python. This is because if you as much as create a reference to an object in a subprocess, it will increment the reference counter for that object and force a copy being made. Therefore, I suggest also looking into `multiprocesisng.shared_memory` (if `big_data` is more or less read-only) to share a direct memory block without relying on COW and potentially making your code compatible with other systems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is meant to supplement Frank Yellin's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73614688/16310741). I am including this because while a solution was offered, an exact explanation of *why* this happened was missing from the other post.

As stated in the linked answer, a pool (higher level than a `multiprocessing.Process`) is meant to survive until you explicitly shut it down. Over it's lifetime it creates and manages a bunch of Processes, supplying them with new work as it comes in. But for this to happen, it needs some way to communicate with the processes it has started. Since `multiprocessing.Process` does not offer a way to do so directly, pools use a bunch of queues internally to transfer work (this includes arguments to target function, and any return values gathered from workers). So, anything you pass to a pool will be placed on a queue, and this is where the difference occurs.

This is because if you go through the documentation, you will find a [note](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) that informs you that whenever an object is put on a queue, it is serialized. Hence start methods are irrelevant, you put something on a queue, it will be pickled. Generalizing, when you use a pool to start a target function, all necessary arguments to start the work will need to be serialized, regardless of of the start method or OS used. This is not the case for the lower-level `Process` class, where no such queues are used, and whether the arguments are pickled or not depends on the start method. This is also the reason why you can pass locks, queues and pipes as arguments to `Process` class, but not when using pools.

One last thing of note here is that when you do `p.imap_unordered(comp.compute, compute_input)`, while you are not passing `big_data` as an argument explicitly, it will still be pickled since the target function is an instance method, and to start that you would need to pickle the instance attributes which includes `big_data`. Hence, when the target function is an instance method, all instance attributes are implicit arguments that will be put on queue by default. So, an alternate to Frank's answer could also be that you convert `compute` to a staticmethod, call it using `type(comp).compute`, and finally use `big_data` without storing it as an instance attribute at all.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you misunderstand the purpose of a process pool.

A call to `mp.process()` creates a process, it does whatever computation you ask it to do, and then it goes away.

A process pool, on the other hand, is longer lived.  Though in your code, you give it only one unit of work, they are designed to perform multiple units of work.  If you had had many tasks, each process would have started the next task when it finished the previous one.  Hence process pools are need to pickle their arguments and send it to the process, since the arguments might not have even existed when the process was created.

Now in your particular case.  You could just write:

```
class Compute:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def compute(self, task_id):
        self.big_data = big_data
        time.sleep(2)
        return "Result"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
    big_data = pickle.load(.......)
```

And you'll see that the pool now run extremely quickly.  The `big_data` is no longer part of the object that needs to be sent over.

Comment: Hey @Frank Yellin, thanks for the answer. I am pretty much aware of what a Pool is therefore ;)  Obviously, my provided example code, is not intend to show how to run acutally multiple tasks, since this was not my initial question^^ The most intersting question is, why does Python not use forking within a Pool and inherit the global ressources as you would do with a call to os.fork() on linux?  It does use it with creating multiple Process() ourselves.

Comment: The code that you have given shows, that Pool from Multiprocessing actually always serializes every input argument first when starting a process, even when using forking. Which is somehow unfortunate. This means when someone would make use of forking and Pool, then it is needed to put the obj ressources not in the context of input arguments of a Pool. This is a huge differnce in what a Process does then.

Comment: since the API of Pool and Process on a high level perspective look the same, which is confusing for this approach. You also give Process a target with input parameters, but instead of serializing it, Pool automatically use inheritance of memory via fork also for those objects.

Comment: I think I answered your question.  I could have changed your variant 2 to move `comp = Compute()` to inside the `with mp.Pool()` statement and it would have worked fine. The pool can be created before the objects, so the pool can't presume that the objects already exist, even with a fork.  This isn't an issue with `mp.Process'.  Yes mp.Pool always serializes every object, because it has to.

Comment: I think you somehow got my comment wrong, it is not about an issue in Pool, this might be expected behaviour, it is just important to show this to other user, so that they do not get confused, of what Pool does when starting a new process with its API definition ;)

Comment: The Pool API could have been designed differntly, in the sense that if forking is the spawn method of the underlying OS, then methods on a pool like .map_unordered() should not serialize their inputs, rather inherit these objects from memory completly, since they already are in the global context and linux can inherit them from the parent memory process.